# Foxit reader does not work on my user specifically

Tags: pdf, c++, foxitreader

I have been using Foxit PDF reader with no problems till I tried to run it now then it failed.
 I don't know what is going on ! 
I tried to run it using the terminal, it gives me this error
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 19) >= this->size() (which is 19)
Aborted (core dumped)`
It seems like some exception in C++ .. 
What am I supposed to do? I know no alternatives of this reader with the same capabilities !
any suggestions ?
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and Foxit reader v2.1.0805 ... 
**Edit:** 
I created a new user and reinstalled the program and it ran successfully ! So I suppose the problem is in my user settings! what could it be?

Comment: uninstall and install

Comment: I've already done that ! Nothing changed !

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? which foxit reader version? edit the answer to include them

Comment: Ok I edited it .

Comment: «I know no alternatives of this reader with the same capabilities» There are plenty of them but that would be a different question. Did you try pruning the configuration files of Foxit Reader from your home directory?

Comment: Can you tell me some of these alternatives but as powerful as Foxit ...

Comment: and thanks, you helped me to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEM SOLVED.**

Apparently the problem was localized to my user account and thus - I guess - to my home directory .. 
So, and thanks to ***[Andrea Lazzarotto](https://askubuntu.com/users/271/andrea-lazzarotto)***, I deleted Foxit-related files in a hidden directory named `.local` in my home directory and the problem solved ..
The directory was filled with a bunch of error logs but honestly, I don't exactly understand what happened .. 
I put the answer here to help anyone who may fall in the same problem

Comment: Can you check again if the folder is in `.local`? I found only in ~/.config/

Comment: Yes, it's there. The path is /home/< _username_ >/.local/share/Foxit Software

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove the files by running this command:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Foxit\ Software/
```

(Just make sure *not* to accidentally insert a space after the `~` or `~/`. If you do, you'll be deleting your whole home directory, rather than just the `Foxit Software` directory!)